# Creating test users with password hash in asp.net identity 2.2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity-2

I would like to create some test users for my ASP.net MVC
application. The version of identity is 2.2.1

My code generates users nicely, but I would like assign passwords that 
would allow these test accounts to login.  So I beleive I need to call 
the same hashing function used when users are created the normal way.

My code is

```
ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
...

for (var i=0; i<100; i++)
{
    var name = "User" + i;
    var user = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == name);

    if (user == null)
    {
        user = new ApplicationUser() {
                        UserName = name,
                        Email = name + "@" + name + "." + name,
                        PasswordHash = ?????hash of name ?????
                    };
         db.Users.Add(user);
         db.SaveChanges();

    }
}
```

yes, i am trying for a password of User1 for User1, and User2 for User2 and so on.

Regards,
John

Comment: You need to use the UserManager to create the accounts. Check your AccountController and look at how you register new accounts. should give you an idea of what you need to do

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `UserManager` will create the accounts. Assuming you are using the default Identity framework template There should be an `ApplicationUserManager` derived from `UserManager<ApplicationUser>` All the necessary configuration should already be in that class.

```
public async Task CreateTestUsers() {

    var db = new ApplicationDbContext();
    var userStore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(db);
    var userManager = new ApplicationUserManager(userStore);

    for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
        var username = "User" + i;

        var user = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == username);
        if (user == null) {
            user = new ApplicationUser() {
                            UserName = username,
                            Email = username + "@" + username + "." + username,
                            EmailConfirmed = true,
                            LockoutEnabled = false
                        };

            var password = username;
            var result = await userManager.CreateAsync(user, password);
        }
    }
}
```

That should then create the test users just as in the normal way with passwords all hashed and ready for testing.

Comment: thank you. Works perfect. I added EmailConfirm = true and LocloutEnabled=False in the ApplicaitonUser creation.

Comment: I had it initially but removed it to match what you had in your example. As it is necessary for the login, I'll add it back to the answer.

Comment: There are many other non - null values that need to be set when creating users, and how is the security stamp handled?